# PHP How to remove break line \n \r \t from string but keep intact content inside textarea

Tags: php, regex, html

I made ajax to get some HTML from backend, on backend the HTML are inside variable (properly formatted with tabs and break lines), but on ajax I need remove break lines and tabs, but I need keep the content inside textarea intact.

Example, I have this:

```
$myhtml = '
<form class="some class other another">
    <div class="title-box">
        <div class="title">Questions</div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <div>
            <span>Insert title</span>
            <div>
                <input name="question" placeholder="Insert some text here" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="margin-t-10">
            <label>Insert BIO</label>
            <div>
                <textarea name="bio" class="textarea-content">This is first line text
This is second line text

more lines...</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <label>Insert description here</label>
            <div>
                <textarea data-something name="description" class="textarea-content other class">Line one
line two
    have some tabulation here to keep...

another line...</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>';
```

I need some regex to remove `\n \t \r` but keep content inside textarea intact to get this:

```
$afterregex = '<form class="some class other another"><div class="title-box"><div class="title">Questions</div></div><div class="content"><div><span>Insert title</span><div><input name="question" placeholder="Insert some text here" type="text" /></div></div><div class="margin-t-10"><label>Insert BIO</label><div><textarea name="bio" class="textarea-content">This is first line text
This is second line text

more lines...</textarea></div></div><div class="description"><label>Insert description here</label><div><textarea data-something name="description" class="textarea-content other class">Line one
line two
    have some tabulation here to keep...

another line...</textarea></div></div></div></form>';
```

I return something like this to frontend (via ajax):

```
exit(json_encode(array(
    'success' => true,
    'content' => $afterregex; // without break lines and tabs
)));
```

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: You say you have that HTML in a variable, do you mean you have literally assigned the HTML string to a variable like you've shown here, or are you pulling it from a database or some other source?

Comment: I don't understand you cant remove them and keep them intact.  The only thing you could do is replace them and then put them back but that makes no sense.  I never had an issue with AJAX and new lines.  I think you need to explain what you want a bit better.  Also what is the value of `data-something` with no `=`

Comment: Oh, I think I figured it out, you want to minify the HTML but leave the line returns in the `textarea` right?

Comment: I get data from API (in JSON), so I need mount HTML with this data and return to frontend (the HTML is just a example). After I mount HTML, I need remove break line and tabulations, but the text inside tag textarea needs to keep intact with break lines and tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, I cant gurantee this will work in every case.  Basically it keeps the spaces inside Open and Close tags.  So it will keep any space between `<tag>` and `</tag>` but remove them between `</tag>` and `<othertag>`.

```
function minify( $html )
{
   return preg_replace('/>\s+<(?!\/textarea)/', '><', $html);
}


$myhtml = <<<HTML
<form class="some class other another">
    <div class="title-box">
        <div class="title">Questions</div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <div>
            <span>Insert title</span>
            <div>
                <input name="question" placeholder="Insert some text here" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="margin-t-10">
            <label>Insert BIO</label>
            <div>
                <textarea name="bio" class="textarea-content">This is first line text
This is second line text

more lines...</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <label>Insert description here</label>
            <div>
                <textarea data-something name="description" class="textarea-content other class">

            Line one
line two
    have some tabulation here to keep...

another line...</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
HTML;

echo minify($myhtml);
```

Try it online

https://3v4l.org/2Y2E2

I added a couple blank start lines in where you had the second textarea.  Here is the output:

```
<form class="some class other another"><div class="title-box"><div class="title">Questions</div></div><div class="content"><div><span>Insert title</span><div><input name="question" placeholder="Insert some text here" type="text" /></div></div><div class="margin-t-10"><label>Insert BIO</label><div><textarea name="bio" class="textarea-content">This is first line text
This is second line text

more lines...</textarea></div></div><div class="description"><label>Insert description here</label><div><textarea data-something name="description" class="textarea-content other class">

Line one
line two
    have some tabulation here to keep...

another line...</textarea></div></div></div></form>
```

To explain the Regex `/>\s+<(?!\/textarea)/`

- `/` open delimiter
- `>` match `>` literally
- `\s+` match one or more whitespace
- `<` match `<` literally
- `(?!\/textarea)` negative look ahead will not match `/textarea`

Then we replace any matches with `><`.

Now the English version.  Match the closing chevron `>` of any tag `tag>`.  Match one or more white spaces. Match the opening chevron `<`.  Do not match `/textarea`.  If any of these match it means no match.  When you put the `<` opening chevron with the negative look ahead, you get `</textarea`.  So this will match anything but `>    </textarea` as in `<textarea class="foo" >   </textarea>`.  So as you can see we can exclude the content area of the textarea tag.

The  `<<<` stuff is another way to indicate a string. It's called a HEREDOC and takes the form of `<<<{tag} ... {tag};`. It acts just like using the double quote `"` in that you can put a PHP variables in and it will be interpolated (replace with it's value). There is also a simular one for the `'` single quote that does not interpolate variables. This is called a NEWDOC and takes this form `<<<'{tag}' ... {tag};` The most important thing to remember is that the end tag has to be on a line all by itself, not even a single space before or after it or it won't work.  If the advantage of using this isn't obvious, it's because you are not using either style of quote `'` or `"` then you can use both of them in the HEREDOC/NEWDOC.

```
//HEREDOC, you can put just $var, or I like to do {$var}
$myhtml = <<<STUFF
<form id='someId' class="some class other another" action="{$url}" >
     <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" $checked />
</form>
STUFF; //<-- this has to be the only thing on this line, no spaces, even this comment can't be here..

//NEWDOC
$myhtml = <<<'OTHERSTUFF'
<form id='someId' class="some class other another" action="must/be/entered/manual" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
</form>
OTHERSTUFF; //<-- this also has to be the only thing on this line
```

### UPDATE

I wasn't really happy with the Regex only version of this.  The main reason is that it won't fix content in other tags, like this..

```
//won't any of these
<p>
    This will retain it's white space because it doesn't match \s+

    Something like this would leave all the whitespace
</p>
< span >  stuff   < / span >
//and it doesn't remove
 <!-- comments -->
//in javascript there may be issues with HTML in strings
var = "<div>in javascript</div>";
```

So obviously this is not ideal.  But the fix for this is more complex then it would seem, or at least it's beyond my not insubstantial ability with Regex.  In any case anyone with any real knowlage of regex will say you cant parse HTML with it. That's not entirely true though as you can use it to create a Lexer/Tokenizer.

Which is exactly what I did, because ... well ... this post wasn't long enough as it was. Not to mention I may find a use for it myself.

You can find it on my [GitHub HERE](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/Lexers/HtmlMinifier.php) I removed all the comments to reduce the size as much as I could in the version pasted below.  But this was fun and I really wanted to share it.

```
class Minifier{

    const MODE_CLOSED = 'closed';

    const MODE_OPEN = 'open';

    const MODE_IGNORE = 'ignore';

    protected $ignoreTags = [
        'script',
        'style'
    ];

    protected $tokens =  [
        'T_EOF'             => '\Z',
        'T_COMMENT'         => '<(?=!--).+(?<=--)>',
        'T_OPEN_TAG'        => '<(?!\/)[^>]+(?<!\/)>',
        'T_CLOSE_TAG'       => '<(?=\/)[^>]+(?<!\/)>',
        'T_INLINE_TAG'      => '<(?!\/)[^>]+(?<=\/)>',
        'T_ENCAPSED_STRING' => '(?P<Q>\'|").*?(?<!\\\\)\k<Q>',
        'T_STRING'          => '[-\w]+',
        'T_WHITESPACE'      => '\s+',
        'T_UNKNOWN'         => '.+?'
    ];

    public function __construct($addTags = [], $removeTags = []){
        $this->unsetTag($removeTags);
        $this->setTag($addTags);
    }

    public function issetTag($ignoreTags)
    {
        return in_array($ignoreTags,$this->ignoreTags);
    }

    public function setTag($ignoreTags)
    {
        if(empty($ignoreTags)) return;
        if(!is_array($ignoreTags)) $ignoreTags = [$ignoreTags];     
        $this->ignoreTags = array_unique(array_merge($this->ignoreTags, $ignoreTags));   
    }

    public function unsetTag($ignoreTags)
    {
        if(empty($ignoreTags)) return;
        if(!is_array($ignoreTags)) $ignoreTags = [$ignoreTags];
        $this->ignoreTags = array_diff($this->ignoreTags, $ignoreTags);
    }

    public function minify($html)
    {
        $token_stream = $this->lexTokens($html);
        return $this->parseTokens($token_stream);
    }

    public function lexTokens($html)
    {
        $types = array_keys($this->tokens);
        $patterns = [];
        $token_stream = [];
        $result = false;
        foreach ($this->tokens as $k=>$v){
            $patterns[] = "(?P<$k>$v)";
        }
        $pattern = "/".implode('|', $patterns)."/is";
        if (preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
            foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $value) {
                $match = [];
                foreach ($types as $type) {
                    $match = $matches[$type][$key];
                    if (is_array($match) && $match[1] != -1) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                $tok  = [
                    'content' => $match[0],
                    'type' => $type,
                    'offset' => $match[1]
                ];
                $token_stream[] = $tok;
            }
        }
        return $token_stream;
    }

    protected function parseTokens( array &$token_stream )
    {  
        $mode = 'closed';

        $string = '';
        $result = '';

        while($current = current($token_stream)){  
            $content = $current['content'];
            $type = $current['type'];

            next($token_stream);
            switch($type){  
                case 'T_COMMENT':
                break;
                case 'T_OPEN_TAG':
                    if(strlen($string)){
                        if($mode == 'ignore'){
                            $result .= $string;
                        }else{
                            $result .= trim($string);
                        }
                        $string = '';
                    }
                    $content = $this->cleanTag($content);

                    if($this->isIgnoredTag($content)){
                        $mode = 'ignore';
                    }else{
                        $mode = 'open';
                    }
                    $result .= $content;
                break;
                case 'T_INLINE_TAG':
                case 'T_CLOSE_TAG':  
                    if(strlen($string)){
                        if($mode == 'ignore'){
                            $result .= $string;
                        }else{
                            $result .= trim($string);
                        }
                        $string = '';
                    }
                    $content = $this->cleanTag($content);
                    $result .= $content;
                    $mode = 'closed';               
                break;  
                case 'T_ENCAPSED_STRING':
                case 'T_STRING':
                case 'T_UNKNOWN':
                    switch ($mode){
                        case 'ignore':
                        case 'open':
                        case 'closed':
                            $string .= $content;
                        break;
                        default:
                            print_r($result);
                            throw new Exception("Unknown Mode:$mode for $type value $content", 1002);
                    }   
                break;           
                case 'T_WHITESPACE':
                    switch ($mode){
                        case 'closed':
                        break;
                        case 'open':
                            $string .= ' ';
                        break;
                        case 'ignore':
                            $string .= $content;
                        break;
                        default:
                            print_r($result);
                            throw new Exception("Unknown Mode:$mode for $type value $content", 1002);
                    }   
                break;
                case 'T_EOF': return $result;
                default:
                    print_r($current);
                    print_r($result);
                    throw new Exception("Unknown token $type value $content", 1001);
            }
        }
    }

    protected function cleanTag($tag)
    {
        return preg_replace([
            '/\s{2,}/',            
            '/^<\s+/',
            '/^<\/\s+/',
            '/\s+>$/',
            '/\s\/>$/'
         ],[
            ' ',
            '<',
            '</',
            '>',
            '/>',
         ], $tag);
    }

    protected function isIgnoredTag($htmlTag)
    {
        if(!preg_match('/<\/?([a-z]+)\b/i', $htmlTag, $tagName))
            throw new Exception("Cound not parse HTML tag name $htmlTag", 1000);
       return in_array($tagName[1],$this->ignoreTags);
    }
}
```

Test String, I added some of the stuff mentioned. Including some hideously written tags..

```
$html = <<<HTML
<style type="text/css" >
.body, div
{
    background-color: #CCC;
}

#someid
{
   color: #fff;
}
</style>
<p>
This is
            a
stupid p tag
            that has
    all     kinds   of  extra   space   in  it.
</p>
<   span  id="foo"  >Insert title<  /    span    ><!-- extra space in this tag, comments are removed -->
<
br
><!-- new line tag -->
<br  /  ><!-- spaced inline tag -->
<form class="some class other another"> 
    <div class="title-box">
        <div class="title">Questions</div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <div>
            <span>Insert title</span>
            <div>
                <input name="question" placeholder="Insert some text here" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="margin-t-10">
            <label>Insert BIO</label>
            <div>
                <textarea name="bio" class="textarea-content">This is first line text
This is second line text

more lines...</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <label>Insert description here</label>
            <div>
                <textarea data-something name="description" class="textarea-content other class">

Line one
line two
    have some tabulation here to keep...

another line...</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var div = "<div>foobar</div>";
        var span = '<span>span</span>';
        $('textarea[name="bio"]').focuus();
        $(form).on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
HTML;
```

Output

```
<style type="text/css">
.body, div
{
    background-color: #CCC;
}

#someid
{
   color: #fff;
}
</style><p>This is a stupid p tag that has all kinds of extra space in it.</p><span id="foo">Insert title</span><form class="some class other another"><div class="title-box"><div class="title">Questions</div></div><div class="content"><div><span>Insert title</span><div><input name="question" placeholder="Insert some text here" type="text"/></div></div><div class="margin-t-10"><label>Insert BIO</label><div><textarea name="bio" class="textarea-content">This is first line text
This is second line text

more lines...</textarea></div></div><div class="description"><label>Insert description here</label><div><textarea data-something name="description" class="textarea-content other class">

Line one
line two
    have some tabulation here to keep...

another line...</textarea></div></div></div></form><script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var div = "<div>foobar</div>";
        var span = '<span>span</span>';
        $('textarea[name="bio"]').focuus();
        $(form).on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Usage

```
//plain text for display purposes
header('Content-type: text/plain'); 

/*
 construct accepts 2 arguments, as strings or arrays
 the first is add tag(s) to preserve white space on
 the second is remove tag(s) from the white space list
 script and style tags are preserved by default
*/
//this is what was done for the output above
echo (new Minifier('textarea'))->minify($html);

//minify all
echo (new Minifier([], ['script','style']))->minify($html);
```

And last but not least try it online

https://3v4l.org/AQmbS

Enjoy, and sorry this was so long.

Comment: Very close, thanks, but don't solve yet... On second textarea, the blank line and tabulation are removed, but it had to have remained.

Comment: I smallified it some, but it's not going to work with a beginning spaces in the text area.  I'll see If I can come up with something, but that complicates things immensely.

Comment: @rafaelfndev - It should be fixed now, It will even let you start the textbox with a blank line.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! Thanks for explanation too :)

Comment: It won't replace tags with content in them, like a `<p>\nfoobar\n</n>` tag.  Not sure if that matters.  But you start bordering on what is possible with a single Regex.

Comment: Otherwise you can make a token parser to do it but it's much more complex.   Here is one I did that decodes JSON object, JSON without the `"` quotes on [GitHub](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/Lexers/JasonDecoder.php)  I might make a magnifier for the fun of it... :)

Comment: @rafaelfndev - I wrote a much better lexer for you, sorry took so long, had to go to the store, eat, visit with the family etc...